# Visual Studio reports a missing method in a Roslyn Analyser but it is definitely there

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio-2015, roslyn, analyzer

I'm trying to use this analyser ( I wrote it )

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Weingartner.Json.Migration.Analyzer/
https://github.com/Weingartner/Migrations.Json.Net

I apply it against this source file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Weingartner.Json.Migration;

namespace testjson
{
    [DataContract]
    [Migratable("")]
    public class Class1
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int foo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and I see the following warning in the output.

> 1>CSC : warning CS8032: An instance of analyzer
>   **Weingartner.Json.Migration.Roslyn.MigrationHashAnalyzer** cannot be created from
>   C:\Users\phelan\workspace\testjson\packages\Weingartner.Json.Migration.Analyzer.1.0.4\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Weingartner.Json.Migration.Roslyn.dll
>   : Method **'get_SupportedDiagnostics'** in type
>   'Weingartner.Json.Migration.Roslyn.MigrationHashAnalyzer' from
>   assembly 'Weingartner.Json.Migration.Roslyn, Version=1.0.6246.21734,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an
>   implementation..

which is quite strange because if I crack open the DLL with JustDecompile I see

```
[DiagnosticAnalyzer("C#", new string[] {  })]
public class MigrationHashAnalyzer : DiagnosticAnalyzer
{
    <snip>
    public override ImmutableArray<DiagnosticDescriptor> SupportedDiagnostics
    {
        get
        {
            return ImmutableArray.Create<DiagnosticDescriptor>(MigrationHashAnalyzer.Rule);
        }
    }
    <snip>
}
```

which is what I expect because the source for the analyzer compiles. If the method was really missing then it wouldn't compile.

Why would VS report a method missing when it is really there?

Comment: can there be a namespace mismatch? "Weingartner.Json.Migration.Analyzer" as opposed to "Weingartner.Json.Migration.Roslyn"?

Comment: The error says __Weingartner.Json.Migration.Roslyn.MigrationHashAnalyzer__ and the dll  has __Weingartner.Json.Migration.Roslyn.MigrationHashAnalyzer__. Identical. Anyway it is not that it cannot find the class. It is claiming that a method is missing on the class. Wierd.

Comment: What version of `System.Collections.Immutable` are you referencing?

Comment: there are three possibly related posts, have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39615981/1132334 and especially http://stackoverflow.com/a/14521695/1132334 and yet better http://stackoverflow.com/a/948787/1132334

Comment: Version 1.2.1.0 of System.Collections.Immutable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeLoadException says 'no implementation', but it is implemented](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948785/typeloadexception-says-no-implementation-but-it-is-implemented)

Comment: Try dropping down to [version 1.1.36](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Collections.Immutable/1.1.36) instead.

Comment: That did the trick. @DavidG Would you mind adding this as an answer along with how you actually know what the correct version should be. I think I updated the ImmutableCollections version during a routine upgrade process and then didn't notice the analyzer was broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio is quite particular about the version of the libraries it uses. VS itself uses [version 1.1.36](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Collections.Immutable/1.1.36) of the `System.Collections.Immutable` package. Since your analyser uses a different version, the runtime is unable to find the method and assumes it hasn't been implemented.

Reference: https://johnkoerner.com/code-analysis/creating-a-code-analyzer-using-f/#comment-3073977270

[image]

Comment: @bradgonesurfing There seems to be something wrong with your image. It doesn't display for me.

Comment: @svick Same thing happened for me earlier, but I think imgur were having load issues.