# Installing Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.AspNet causes method not implemented runtime error when deployed to a server but runs fine on Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, iis, azure-signalr

**Error:**

> Method 'MyController' in type 'MyProject.AppStart.Selector' from
>   assembly 'MyProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=......' does not have an implementation.

**Background:**
I have an `ASP.NET` project with `target` framework set to `.NET Framework 4.6.2`. After installing `Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.AspNet` `1.0.0-preview1-103a17`from `nuget package manager`, it builds and runs fine on `Visual Studio 2017`. No problem at all. When I deploy the release to my server and try to access any of its services, I get the above-mentioned error. The method is implemented in a class which implements `System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.IHttpControllerSelector`.

**Configuration:**

- The machine on which code works: Windows 10 Version 1809 (OS Build 17763.316). Visual Studio 2017 15.9.6.

[image]

- The machine on which code does not work: Windows Server 2012 R2 Version 6.2 Build 9200. IIS version 8.5.9600.16384.

[image]

**What I tried:**

- Clean/Rebuild deploy again.
- Delete `obj` and `bin` folder, publish and deploy again.
- Deleted CachedAssessmbly as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49173875/9411757).
- Change Configuration from `Release` to `Debug`.
- Install `Azure SDK` in the `Windows Server 2012 R2` machine.
- Try to install the dependencies of `Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.AspNet` without directly installing `Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.AspNet`. It appears that the error starts to `Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.Protocols` is installed. The dependencies of the `Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.Protocols` are:

[image]

All of these four dependencies are being added when I install `Microsoft.Azure.SignalR.Protocols` i.e. they are not already being used.

I can't seem to find the issue.

**Update:**
I deployed the folder on the above mentioned Windows 10 machine and used `IIS Manager` to create an application. The application works fine on the same machine without Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `Windows Server 2012 R2` machine, I had originally installed `.NET Core 2.2 runtime` instead of the `SDK`. I installed the following in order:

1. .NET Core 2.2 SDK (deployment still didn't work)
2. .NET Framework 4.7.2 Dev Pack (asked for restarted, postponed it)
3. .NET Framework 4.6.1 Dev Pack

After installing the `.NET Framework 4.6.1 Dev Pack`, I restarted. And now the deployment **works**.

I can't pinpoint the solution but my guess is that installing `.NET Core 2.2 SDK` fixed the issue. After it got installed, the installation window prompted some version of `Microsoft.AspNetCore` has been installed. It didn't ask for a restart but I guess as `.NET Core 2.2 Runtime` was already installed and being used by another application, a restart was needed.

It is quite strange that `Microsoft.AspNetCore` wasn't installed along with `.NET Core 2.2 Runtime`.

It took quite some time to fix this issue as **typeloadexception** can arise in many other scenarios.

Hope this solution helps other people as well.